# Updating Google Contacts via API shows success in response yet creates duplicate records

Tags: google-api, gdata, gdata-api, google-contacts-api, google-shared-contacts

I'm coming across this strange behavior where when utilizing the batch processing requests for UPDATING existing contacts in Google Contacts, I'm finding despite coming back as a success, it creates duplicate records.

It definitely did NOT do this throughout my development and testing, only recently.  And the only difference I can ascertain is that now I'm working with rather large data sets - a few thousand contacts instead of just a hundred or so.

Here's the raw XML going over the wire for two contacts, both of which were duplicated: http://pastebin.com/diSFzkeu

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oversight on my part.  My groupId wasn't set and it was picking up identical customers from previous tests that I had deleted and were sitting in the deleted (other contacts) folder and restoring them.